# Can I set a "goto" database in SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a connection to my database on a website, the thing is the hoster also has all the other databases here (thousands of them) -- I'm locked out of all of them except mine, so I don't even know why I'm seeing them.

Right now when I connect through the connection, I have to open the Databases folder, then look for my database. I was wondering if I can just hide the other ones? Or make it so it goes to mine as soon as the connection starts.

I've already set the default database as mine, but it doesn't seem to go to it when I connect.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any way of doing this in SSMS object explorer.

Some of the tree view nodes allow you to set a filter but this doesn't seem to apply to the list of the databases.

See if you can get the hoster to deny you the [`VIEW ANY DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077.aspx) permission. You might also point out the problem and suggest that they simply remove this permission from the public role.

BTW in Object Explorer typing the initial letter of your database will at least move you to the right part of the tree (assuming they aren't all named with the same initial letter of course!) and from a quick test this end typing the whole name does actually move you to the correct database.